# What routes are necessary when the Model and Controller names do not match?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Model called Category and another called Articles. Categories are "sections" that have many Articles, for instance News and Events. Both Categories use the kind of Articles, except they're shown under a different section of my website.

Right now I'm creating the News controller (NewsController), and I'd like to visit `/news/new` to add News. Likewise, the same would apply to EventsController and `/events/new`.

What do I have to use on my routes to do this?

My first attempt was to use:

```
resources :categories do
  resources :articles, path: '/news'
end
```

But this forces me to use `/categories/1/news/new`, which is kinda ugly.

If News will always be `category_id` 1 and Events will always be 2, how would I specify this on my routes, so I can easily access them with the URLs I mentioned?

### Explained Differently

I have an Articles model. I'd like to have a controller called NewsController to handle Articles, so that `/news/new` (and the rest of the paths) would work with Article. I'd also like to have a controller called EventsController that would also handle Articles, so that `/events` would also work with Article. The difference between them is that they have different `category_id`.

Is this possible to do via routes?

### Update

Made some progress.

```
resources :categories do
  resources :articles
end

get 'news/new' => 'articles#new', defaults: {category_id: 1}
get 'events/new' => 'articles#new', defaults: {category_id: 2}
```

This fixes what I wanted to do with `/news/new` and `/events/new`, but I'd be missing the rest of the routes (edit, show, update, etc). Also, this makes me use the Articles controller, which currently does not exist and would also make the News controller obsolete/useless.

My logic may be wrong, it's kinda evident with what I just made, but perhaps with this update I can better illustrate what I'm trying to do.

### Update 2

I'm currently testing the following:

```
resources :articles, path: '/news', controller: 'news'
resources :articles, path: '/events', controller: 'events'
```

So far it makes sense, it makes the routes I wanted, it uses both controllers with their own configurations, and it hasn't spat any errors when I visit both `/news` and `/events` (yet).

It's also possible to do:

```
resources :articles, path: '/news', defaults: {category_id: 1}
resources :articles, path: '/events', defaults: {category_id: 2}
```

But this would depend on an Article controller, which could handle both types of Categories. Either solution works (theoretically), though I'd incline more on the first since the individual controllers would allow more specific configuration to both cases. The second, though, is more adequate when there're not that many difference between the Articles being created. The `defaults` property isn't explicitly necessary either, I just put it there for convenience.

Comment: routes have nothing to do with models whatsoever, nada. They only care about controllers. So, model name not matching controller name is not a factor here.

Comment: That's not the issue, I'm aware of that. If both the controller and the model share the same name (which is what you do normally) then the default routes work. However, I'm not using the same Controller name, so the `resources` aren't tied with helpers such as `form_for`. What I want is to be able to use `form_for` and take everything I throw at `/news` as if it was sent to Article. Likewise, I want the same for `/events` and the Events controller, the difference is in the `category_id` they have, though I think it's kinda irrelevant when handled by the controller itself.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Well, in this case, you'd be going against rails' conventions. Which simply means you'll have to do more configuration. `form_for @news, url: article_url(@news` or something like that.

Comment: Yeah, it's against convention. I was hoping there could be a solution with routes, so I avoid having to create two models (News and Events) that have exactly the same fields and properties.

Comment: Just doing more configuration is not an acceptable solution, in your eyes? to me, duplicating models like that is a far bigger sin.

Comment: I don't mind going that route (tehe), but I wanted to explore other options in case there's a much simpler way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is asking something that I question as not making sense and maybe your design is flawed.

Why would you have news resources related to category resources if they are not related?

Is categories just a name space?

If news records really are always going to be related to the same first category as your question implies then you can not use ID's as you have no control over what the id will be for the first category and the first category could have an ID of anything in which case you could just use the top level news resources and do a find first category in your model in a before create then you don't have to worry about an ugly url.

If news records really are related to categories then the you must supply the relevant category id and nest your routes but you could pretty up the url using the following from

https://gist.github.com/jcasimir/1209730

Which states the following

> Friendly URLs
>
> By default, Rails applications build URLs based on the primary key --
>   the id column from the database. Imagine we have a Person model and
>   associated controller. We have a person record for Bob Martin that has
>   id number 6. The URL for his show page would be:
>
> /people/6
>
> But, for aesthetic or SEO purposes, we want Bob's name in the URL. The
>   last segment, the 6 here, is called the "slug". Let's look at a few
>   ways to implement better slugs. Simple Approach
>
> The simplest approach is to override the to_param method in the Person
>   model. Whenever we call a route helper like this:
>
> person_path(@person)
>
> Rails will call to_param to convert the object to a slug for the URL.
>   If your model does not define this method then it will use the
>   implementation in ActiveRecord::Base which just returns the id.
>
> For this method to succeed, it's critical that all links use the
>   ActiveRecord object rather than calling id. Don't ever do this:
>
> person_path(@person.id) # Bad!
>
> Instead, always pass the object:
>
> person_path(@person)
>
> Slug Generation
>
> Instead, in the model, we can override to_param to include a
>   parameterized version of the person's name:
>
> class Person < ActiveRecord::Base   def to_param
>       [id, name.parameterize].join("-")   end end
>
> For our user Bob Martin with id number 6, this will generate a slug
>   6-bob_martin. The full URL would be:
>
> /people/6-bob-martin
>
> The parameterize method from ActiveSupport will deal with converting
>   any characters that aren't valid for a URL. Object Lookup
>
> What do we need to change about our finders? Nothing! When we call
>   Person.find(x), the parameter x is converted to an integer to perform
>   the SQL lookup. Check out how to_i deals with strings which have a mix
>   of letters and numbers:
>
> > "1".to_i
> >
> > ## => 1
> >
> > "1-with-words".to_i
> >
> > ## => 1
> >
> > "1-2345".to_i
> >
> > ## => 1
> >
> > "6-bob-martin".to_i
> >
> > ## => 6
>
> The to_i method will stop interpreting the string as soon as it hits a
>   non-digit. Since our implementation of to_param always has the id at
>   the front followed by a hyphen, it will always do lookups based on
>   just the id and discard the rest of the slug. Benefits / Limitations
>
> We've added content to the slug which will improve SEO and make our
>   URLs more readable.
>
> One limitation is that the users cannot manipulate the URL in any
>   meaningful way. Knowing the url 6-bob-martin doesn't allow you to
>   guess the url 7-russ-olsen, you still need to know the ID.
>
> And the numeric ID is still in the URL. If this is something you want
>   to obfuscate, then the simple scheme doesn't help. Using a Non-ID
>   Field
>
> Sometimes you want to get away from the ID all together and use
>   another attribute in the database for lookup. Imagine we have a Tag
>   object that has a name column. The name would be something like ruby
>   or rails. Link Generation
>
> Creating links can again override to_param:
>
> class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base   validates_uniqueness_of :name
>        def to_param
>       name   end end
>
> Now when we call tag_path(@tag) we'd get a URL like /tags/ruby. Object
>   Lookup
>
> The lookup is harder, though. When a request comes in to /tags/ruby
>   the ruby will be stored in params[:id]. A typical controller will call
>   Tag.find(params[:id]), essentially Tag.find("ruby"), and it will fail.
>   Option 1: Query Name from Controller
>
> Instead, we can modify the controller to
>   Tag.find_by_name(params[:id]). It will work, but it's bad
>   object-oriented design. We're breaking the encapsulation of the Tag
>   class.
>
> The DRY Principle says that a piece of knowledge should have a single
>   representation in a system. In this implementation of tags, the idea
>   of "A tag can be found by its name" has now been represented in the
>   to_param of the model and the controller lookup. That's a maintenance
>   headache. Option 2: Custom Finder
>
> In our model we could define a custom finder:
>
> class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base   validates_uniqueness_of :name
>        def to_param
>       name   end
>        def self.find_by_param(input)
>       find_by_name(input)   end end
>
> Then in the controller call Tag.find_by_param(params[:id]). This layer
>   of abstraction means that only the model knows exactly how a Tag is
>   converted to and from a parameter. The encapsulation is restored.
>
> But we have to remember to use Tag.find_by_param instead of Tag.find
>   everywhere. Especially if you're retrofitting the friendly ID onto an
>   existing system, this can be a significant effort. Option 3:
>   Overriding Find
>
> Instead of implementing the custom finder, we could override the find
>   method:
>
> class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base   #...   def self.find(input)
>       find_by_name(input)   end end
>
> It will work when you pass in a name slug, but will break when a
>   numeric ID is passed in. How could we handle both?
>
> The first temptation is to do some type switching:
>
> class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base   #...   def self.find(input)
>       if input.is_a?(Integer)
>         super
>       else
>         find_by_name(input)
>       end   end end
>
> That'll work, but checking type is very against the Ruby ethos.
>   Writing is_a? should always make you ask "Is there a better way?"
>
> Yes, based on these facts:
>
> ```
> Databases give the id of 1 to the first record
> Ruby converts strings starting with a letter to 0
> ```
>
> class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base   #...   def self.find(input)
>       if input.to_i != 0
>         super
>       else
>         find_by_name(input)
>       end   end end
>
> Or, condensed down with a ternary:
>
> class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base   #...   def self.find(input)
>       input.to_i == 0 ? find_by_name(input) : super   end end
>
> Our goal is achieved, but we've introduced a possible bug: if a name
>   starts with a digit it will look like an ID. If it's acceptable to our
>   business domain, we can add a validation that names cannot start with
>   a digit:
>
> class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base   #...   validates_format_of :name,
>   :without => /^\d/   def self.find(input)
>       input.to_i == 0 ? find_by_name(input) : super   end end
>
> Now everything should work great! Using the FriendlyID Gem
>
> Does implementing two additional methods seem like a pain? Or, more
>   seriously, are you going to implement this kind of functionality in
>   multiple models of your application? Then it might be worth checking
>   out the FriendlyID gem: https://github.com/norman/friendly_id Setup
>
> The gem is just about to hit a 4.0 version. As of this writing, you
>   want to use the beta. In your Gemfile:
>
> gem "friendly_id", "~> 4.0.0.beta8"
>
> Then run bundle from the command line. Simple Usage
>
> The minimum configuration in your model is:
>
> class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base   extend FriendlyId   friendly_id :name
>   end
>
> This will allow you to use the name column or the id for lookups using
>   find, just like we did before. Dedicated Slug
>
> But the library does a great job of maintaining a dedicated slug
>   column for you. If we were dealing with articles, for instance, we
>   don't want to generate the slug over and over. More importantly, we'll
>   want to store the slug in the database to be queried directly.
>
> The library defaults to a String column named slug. If you have that
>   column, you can use the :slugged option to automatically generate and
>   store the slug:
>
> class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base   extend FriendlyId   friendly_id
>   :name, :use => :slugged end
>
> Usage
>
> You can see it in action here:
>
> > t = Tag.create(:name => "Ruby on Rails")
> >
> > ## => #
> >
> > Tag.find 16
> >
> > ## => #
> >
> > Tag.find "ruby-on-rails"
> >
> > ## => #
> >
> > t.to_param
> >
> > ## => "ruby-on-rails"
>
> We can use .find with an ID or the slug transparently. When the object
>   is converted to a parameter for links, we'll get the slug with no ID
>   number. We get good encapsulation, easy usage, improved SEO and easy
>   to read URLs.

Comment: Categories will have many Articles, in my example category_id 1 is News, 2 is Events. The IDs I mentioned are arbitrary at this point, although at some point they will be fixed, however I do not know how many categories I will have at the end. The News and Events controller are just for UI representation as to what section the Article belongs to. I updated my question with the progress I've made.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure there will be only 2 categories, why not simply add a boolean to the articles?

Like: `article.event` = true if events category, false if news

Then you can add a scopes to Article class for both categories

```
class Article
  scope :events, -> { where(event: true) }
  scope :news, -> { where(event: false) }
end
```

Create controllers, for example:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @articles = Article.events
  end

  def create
    @article.new(params)
    @article.event = true
    @article.save
  end

  ...
end
```

and routes: `resources :events`

Comment: There will be more Categories, I simply mentioned those two as examples and the hypothetical IDs of 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use dynamic segments: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments

Add some slug attribute to Category, it should be unique and add index to it.

```
# routes
resources :articles, except: [:index, :new]
get '*category_slug/new', to: 'articles#new'
get '*category_slug', to: 'articles#index'

# controller
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @category = Category.find_by slug: params[:category_slug]
    @articles = @category.articles
  end

  def new
    @category = Category.find_by slug: params[:category_slug]
    @article = @category.articles.build
  end

  ...
end
```

Remember to put a category in a hidden field in the `form_for @article`